# parsing MIDI file with unknown bytes

Tags: midi

I have a midi file which was generated using MuseScore. It plays well in Windows Media Player, but causes my midi reading program to crash.

```
4d 54 68 64 = MThd
00 00 00 06 = Header length of 6
00 01 = Track format 1
00 02 = two tracks
01 e0 = 480 delta-ticks per quarter note

4d 54 72 6b = MTrk
00 00 00 86 = length of 0x86
00 ff 58 04 04 02 18 08 = time signature
00 ff 59 02 00 00 = key signature
00 c0 00 = program change (channel 1)
02 b0 07 64 = control mode change (channel 1)
02 0a = running status
40 02 = running status
5b 1e = running status
02 5d = running status
1e ac 78 90 = Aftertouch event (channel 13, not really applicable in this context)
3e 50 = running status
83 5f 3e = delta time (83 5f) and 3e, which is not a status byte
(more bytes for context): 00 01 40 50
```

What exists in the MIDI standard that I've overlooked here?

Lots of edits later: For those who read this earlier, I completely misread the MIDI file when I first wrote this, due to lag in Notepad++. I've got the correct bytes now, and I'm sure of it.